# Efficient way of managing a mongodb database in a VM instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently started to test GAE, and I'm trying to build a small website managed with Angular + mongodb in the backend.
I have created a VM instance with mongodb to store the database but I haven't found a good way to manage the database(s), I would like to enter via mongo shell or another tool like mongo-express.

I'm trying the first option now, but I noticed the VM instance is very limited in what is installed, it's not shipped with the usual CLI tools, and right now the shell doesn't start because it fails with:

```
Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user locale set. Please ensure LANG and/or LC_* environment variables are set correctly.
```

I wonder is there's a faster way of having a functional mongodb database with remote access for management or do I need to install all packages and configure the VM accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to deploy MongoDB using Google's Click-to-Deploy technology. It will help you to deploy GCE instances with MongoDB installed and configured and ready for your use, including the CLI tools you'll need to manage the database.

https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/mongodb?cat=DATABASE